# how to enable near by (corresponding) textbox when checkboxs checked which are in tabcontainer in asp.net,c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am just started leaning asp.net.With your all support I hope I will learn bit extra from this forum.

My issue is,

I have a TabContainer1 in asp.net page,in that I have multiple like (60) check boxes and multiple(60) textboxes in each tab panel.
Now If I check any checkbox ,corresponding or (near by) text to be enabled.
for that I am doing like below

```
<tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td align="left" style="width: 5%;">
        PPID[OP_ppid]:
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkppid" runat="server" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtppid" Enabled="false" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="width: 5%;">
        CONTROL NO[Op_ControlNo]:
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcontrolno" runat="server" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontrolno" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left" style="width: 5%;">
        MODEL NO[OP_modelno]:
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmodelno" runat="server" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtmodelno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="width: 5%;">
        OEM SERIALNo[op_oemserialno]:
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkoemserNo" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtoemserno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

like that 60 textboxes in each table panel.
and I doing like as below for enabling and disabling

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function enableTextBox()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= chkppid.ClientID %>").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("<%= txtppid.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("<%= txtppid.ClientID %>").disabled = true;

       if (document.getElementById("<%= chkcontrolno.ClientID %>").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("<%= txtcontrolno.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("<%= txtcontrolno.ClientID %>").disabled = true;

        if (document.getElementById("<%= chkmodelno.ClientID %>").checked == true)
            document.getElementById("<%= txtmodelno.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("<%= txtmodelno.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

Please suggest me how to implement for all at once.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop ([`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method off Array in the code bellow) to run over all the checkboxes. The eventlisteners are added in the loop too.Each listener gets the right textbox using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) on the parentNode of the checkbox currently being processed.

HTML with classes for toggling checkboxes and textfield to be toggled:

```
<td style="width: 40%;">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcontrolno" class="toggler" runat="server"/>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontrolno" class="togglee" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox></td>
```

Javascript to add the Eventlistener to each checkbox:

```
var boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".toggler"));
boxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
  var textbox = checkbox.parentNode.querySelector(".togglee");
  if(textbox === null){
    console.error("no textbox found to be toggled by ",checkbox);
  }
  checkbox.onchange = function(){textbox.disabled = !textbox.disabled;};
});
```

---

For old browsers use this JavaScript:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("toggler");
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length;i++){
    boxes[i].onclick=function(event){
        var candidates = event.target.parentNode.childNodes;
        for(var j = 0; j < candidates.length; j++){
            if(candidates[j].className == undefined) continue;
            if(candidates[j].className.indexOf("togglee")>-1){
                candidates[j].disabled = !candidates[j].disabled;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replay,but, `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".toggler"));` is throwing an error.

Comment: `if(candidates[j].attributes.class.value.contains("togglee"))` error at '.class'  as expectedidentifier ,and I am not understanding it.please try to help.

Comment: Seems like `contains`is not a standard method on string. Update the code once more.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName,onclick,target,parentNode and some` are not coming while typing.Do I need to change anything in control declarations?

Comment: Does [it](https://jsfiddle.net/L2wkfvek/2/) work or not? If not what browser do you use for testing?

Comment: it did not work,and I am using mozilla firefox.46.0.1

Comment: That's strange I use the same firefox and for me the linked jsfiddle works.